# option in select box is checked but not show the value

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, dropdown, html-select

**Update solution:**

```
var selectClass = $("#class"); 
$("#class").val(classDeadline);
selectClass.selectmenu("refresh");
```

I have a select box like this in html page

```
<select id="class" class="ui-selectmenu" >
</select>
```

this code to get classes from db and append to select box:

```
function getClasses(tx){
  //alert('classes');
  var sql = "select * from classes";
  tx.executeSql(sql, [] , getClasses_success);
}

function getClasses_success(tx, results){
  var len = results.rows.length;
  //alert('len: ' + len);
  //var s = "";
  for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
      var classDB = results.rows.item(i);
      $('#class').append('<option value="'+ classDB.name + '">'+ classDB.name +'</option>');
  }
    ////alert('before append');
}
```

the options of select box is retrieved from database. I can make all of the options normally. However, I have a javascript function like this which retrieve a class from database and then make it selected in the selected box. After I tried to make that class to be selected, I checked the html page again. I could see that the class was checked already ( it has the "check" symbol next to value) but the select box doesn't show the value of that selected option. Do you have any idea to have me ?

```
var len = results.rows.length;
//var s = "";
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    var deadline = results.rows.item(i);
    var description = deadline.description;
    var classDeadline = deadline.class;
    var duedate = deadline.duedate;
    var duetime = deadline.duetime;
    var type = deadline.type;
    var additionalInfo = deadline.additionalInfo;
    var finished = deadline.finished;

    document.getElementById("shortDescription").value = description;
    document.getElementById("dueDate").value = duedate;
    document.getElementById("dueTime").value = duetime;
    document.getElementById("additionalInfo").value = additionalInfo;
    $("#class").val(classDeadline);
    document.getElementById("type").selected = type;
    document.getElementById("finished").selected = finished;


}
    //alert('before append');
```

Let's take a look at the code `$("#class").val(classDeadline);`

Checked already: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcMED.png
 But doesn't show any value: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y71dS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was not setting the selected state or appending a new option to the select box.

**After setting the selected attribute to an option, jQ Mobile needs a refresh of the selectbox to display it correctly.**.

```
var myselect = $("#class"); 
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 'HCI'; 
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

---

**jsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/pWgJ7/1/

- please try to change `var classDeadline = deadline.class;` to `var classDeadline = deadline.myclass;`. "class" is an ECMAScipt reserved word.
- check that you have a value in `classDeadline`, before you assign the value to the dom element `$("#class").val(classDeadline);`. Use `console.log(classDeadline)` or `alert(classDeadline)`.

Comment: "class" here is a attribute in my database, so I think it won't conflict . And the browser's console also doesn't say it's conflicted

Comment: I checked again, it can get the value of classDeadline. So it's also selected in the select box as the picture I posted above. The problem is that the value of the selected option is not displayed ( posted pic above also ) :)

Comment: I don't see where multiple options gets set to the select box. I think instead of assigning one value with val() you could try to append() values. val() is correct for setting the selected state by ID... After assigning all the values: $('#class [value='+value+']').prop('selected', true);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vAa9G/43/ . Out of curiosity: Is jQuery loaded? ( because you are using a jQ selector $("#class"))

Comment: multiple options is retrieved from database and set already to select box in another function. Here I just get which class was chosen , and then make it selected in select box.

Comment: yes, the fiddle contains two solution to set the "selected" state.

Comment: In here I just select an option that already set to select box, not appending a new one , it will cause duplication

Comment: Please post the full html code of the select element, so that i can adjust the jsfiddle code to your example..

Comment: Thank you. So value and key are the same (classDB.name): http://jsfiddle.net/pWgJ7/1/

Comment: I tried both but it's just selected and not show the value

Comment: Hmm - strange. Refreshing problem? `var myselect = $("#class");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 'HCI'; myselect.selectmenu("refresh");`

Comment: I don't understand this line much. $("select option[value='HCI']").attr("selected","selected"); 

What if I have multiple select boxes in page, how that line can distinguish which select box it applies for . I don't see the id of select box in the code

Comment: Oh yeah it worked. That's refresh problem as you said. Thank u so much :)

Comment: That was quite hard to find. Glad we solved it :) (my selector is not really good, it grabs every selectbox containing the option and sets the value - this would switch multiple boxes at the same time.)

Comment: Anyway thank u again so much. I'm having project and luckily now I can continue go further with it :)

Comment: I have a problem with another select box: var selectFinished = $("#finished");$("#finished").val(finished);selectFinished.selectmenu("refresh");
When I call the .selectmennu('refresh'), the console said "cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

Comment: try to (force) an initialization before: `$('#finished').selectmenu();`

Comment: I found it. Because data-role of that select box is "flipswitch" so I tried .flipswitch() and it worked